# преобразовать массив в ассоциативный

Tags: javascript, jquery

как преобразовать массив в ассоциативный?
пишу следующее:

```
arr=[one,two,three]
res=[]
$.each(arr,function(idx,el){
    idx+=1
    res.push(idx,el)
})
```

должно быть так `[1:one,2:two,3:three]` а у меня `[1,one,2,two,3,three]`

Comment: какой результат ожидается и как потом планируется его использовать? Ну и судя по коду вам надо просто сделать `unshift` для не значимого элемента и индексы выровнятся

Comment: Как потом будет использоваться результат? вы хотите просто индексы подвинуть?

Comment: ассоциативный массив в JS это объект, поэтому в вашем случае ассоциативный массив выглядит так: {1:one,2:two,3:three}

Comment: @MasterAlex, объект это не массив :)

Comment: @Grundy, напишите об этом авторам учебника: https://learn.javascript.ru/object

Comment: @MasterAlex, ага, у них проблемы с терминологией :)

Comment: @Grundy, у них проблем нет, может у вас есть, потому что ассоциативных массивов в JS нет, поэтому давно принято считать что функционал ассоциативных массивов несут в себе объекты. И да, объект это не массив, утверждение верное, с этим спорить не буду :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, Ну вы уж определитесь :-) либо _ассоциативный массив в JS это объект_ либо _ассоциативных массивов в JS нет_ :-)

Comment: @MasterAlex, нашли на что сослаться. Хотите авторитетных источников -- читайте Флэнагана. js.ru ресурс для новичков, не более того.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, и чтобы не быть голословным предоставьте ссылку на то, как Флэнаган создаёт ассоциативные массивы в JS, я обязательно прочитаю эту статью полностью.

Comment: В js нет и не было ассоциативных массивов в том смысле, в котором вы их понимаете (разговор о `Map` оставим в стороне). Ну и Флэнаган, он про толстые исчерпывающие руководства по JS, а не про статьи. Странно, что вы не в курсе.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, открыл сейчас книгу Флэнагана, и что я вижу: `7.3. Объекты как ассоциативные массивы . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 125`, у него тоже проблемы с терминологией?

Comment: `как` != `является`. Хотите настоящих ассоциативных массивов в JS -- читайте про [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а где по моей "неавторитетной" ссылке написано "является"? Вы ведь явно намекнули, что сайт  learn.javascript.ru/object  - плохое пособие, а у Флэнагана неожиданно написано то же самое в заголовке

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40261/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-masteralex).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, какая-то сложная система авторизации в этом чате, зайти не смог даже после регистрации, поэтому предлагаю закончить беседу, которая не имеет практического смысла, кроме того, что вы мне пытаетесь доказать то, что я и не отрицаю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код просто вставляет в массив несколько элементов. Чтобы получить [{1:one},{2:two},{3:three}] нужно вставлять уже подготовленные объекты:

```
arr=['one','two','three'];
var res=[];
$.each(arr,function(idx,el) {
    var item = {};
    item[idx+1] = el;
    res.push(item);
})
```

Гораздо удобнее пользоваться не массивом с объектами, а объектом со свойствами-индексами

```
{
    1: one,
    2: two,
    3: three,
}
```

Чтобы получить такой объект, вам нужно использовать следующий код:

```
var arr= ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var res = {};
$.each(arr,function(idx,el){         
    res[idx+1] = el;
})
```

Comment: @D-side, скорее всего опечатка при copy-paste не поправлена